# Include the spatial context of pixels during image clustering

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, k-means, gaussian, noise

How can the `spatial context` (or `neighbourhood`) of a pixel be taken into account (besides the pixel `intensity`) when clustering an image?

For the time being, I'm using `K-means`, `GMM` and `Fuzzy C-means` which cluster the image based only on the distribution of the pixel `intensities`. But, I need to include the information on the `spatial context` of the pixel into the clustering, to avoid the misclassification caused by the `noise speckle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard approach for segmentation is to add the X and Y coordinates with appropriate scaling to the color values (in RGB or Lab space).
Examples of these are SLIC (K-means clustering in x-y-Lab space) and Quickshift (an accelerated mean shift in x-y-Lab space).
When also considering spacial distances, it is often possible to gain a lot of speed. Check out the implementations in [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html) or [this blog](http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/superpixels-slic/) or [my blog](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.com/2012/09/segmentation-algorithms-in-scikits-image.html)

Comment: Is the `normalization` of the space `S = (Intensity, X, Y)` using the formula `S = (S - mean) / std_dev` a good scaling?

Comment: It depends on the trade-off between compactness and color homogeneity. I recommend you read the SLIC and quickshift papers.